# How to match phpass hashed password(codeigniter) in java(android)?

Tags: java, android, mysql, codeigniter, phpass

I am developing an android application where I have to synchronize the user table info from a remote mySql database to the sqlite database of android device through API communication. The user table has a field to keep the passwords of the users. These passwords are hashed by a "**Portable PHP password hashing framework**" used in codeigniter framework. The class which is used to create these hashed password in php language(codeigniter framework) is given bellow:

```
<?php

class PasswordHash {
    var $itoa64;
    var $iteration_count_log2;
    var $portable_hashes;
    var $random_state;

    function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
    {
        $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31) $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
        $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

        $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

        $this->random_state = microtime();
        if (function_exists('getmypid')) $this->random_state .= getmypid();
    }

    function get_random_bytes($count)
    {
        $output = '';
        if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') && ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')))
        {
            $output = fread($fh, $count);
            fclose($fh);
        }

        if (strlen($output) < $count)
        {
            $output = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16)
            {
                $this->random_state = md5(microtime().$this->random_state);
                $output .= pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
        }

        return $output;
    }

    function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do
        {
            $value = ord($input[$i ++]);
            $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count) $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i ++ >= $count) break;
            if ($i < $count) $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i ++ >= $count) break;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_private($input)
    {
        $output = '$P$';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[min($this->iteration_count_log2 + ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);

        return $output;
    }

    function crypt_private($password, $setting)
    {
        $output = '*0';
        if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output) $output = '*1';

        $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
        # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
        if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$') return $output;

        $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
        if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30) return $output;

        $count = 1 << $count_log2;

        $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
        if (strlen($salt) != 8) return $output;

        # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
        # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
        # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
        # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
        # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
        # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5')
        {
            $hash = md5($salt.$password, TRUE);
            do
            {
                $hash = md5($hash.$password, TRUE);
            } while (--$count);
        }
        else
        {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt.$password));
            do
            {
                $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash.$password));
            } while (--$count);
        }

        $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
        $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_extended($input)
    {
        $count_log2 = min($this->iteration_count_log2 + 8, 24);
        # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
        # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
        $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;

        $output = '_';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];

        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_blowfish($input)
    {
        # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
        # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
        # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
        # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
        # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
        # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
        # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
        # of entropy.
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        $output = '$2a$';
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 / 10);
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 % 10);
        $output .= '$';

        $i = 0;
        do
        {
            $c1 = ord($input[$i ++]);
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
            $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
            if ($i >= 16)
            {
                $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
                break;
            }

            $c2 = ord($input[$i ++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

            $c2 = ord($input[$i ++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);

        return $output;
    }

    function HashPassword($password)
    {
        $random = '';

        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && ! $this->portable_hashes)
        {
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
            $hash = crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 60) return $hash;
        }

        if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && ! $this->portable_hashes)
        {
            if (strlen($random) < 3) $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
            $hash = crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 20) return $hash;
        }

        if (strlen($random) < 6) $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $this->gensalt_private($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 34) return $hash;

        # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
        # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
        # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
        return '*';
    }

    function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
    {
        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
        if ($hash[0] == '*') $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

        return $hash == $stored_hash;
    }
}

/* End of file phpass_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/account/phpass_helper.php */
```

Now, what I need is to match a user inputted password with these hashed passwords using java codes in android. How can I do that?

***N.B. I have used a [java library](https://github.com/Mollom/phpass-java) for this purpose, but could not able to compare password.***

Comment: Why dont you send request to  api function in php which validate user login and return you login result

Comment: @user1048123 because I want to make an offline login, so that the users can login when internet is unavailable also......